# How to parse second level of json php

Tags: php, json

I have a json like this:

```
[{"a":"1", "b":"2"},{"a":"4", "b":"5"},{"a":"15", "b":"2"}]
```

I want to get in php each row for update my database. I don't know the number of second level json are. Sometimes will be 1, sometimes 2 and sometimes more.

I thought, I could read it doing something like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_post = json_decode($json, true);
$i = 0;

while(isset($json_post[$i])){
//Bla bla
$i++;
}
```

I have used many times json file in php but always, just one level. This is my first time with more than one.
But I can't. I know, because I checked, that in $json I have the complete json file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the subkey in your array:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_post = json_decode($json, true);
$i = 0;

while(isset($json_post[$i])){
    echo $json_post[$i]["a"];
    // or 
    echo $json_post[$i][0];
    $i++;
}
```

More docs can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

And a similar question here: [PHP reference specific key and value within multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862630/php-reference-specific-key-and-value-within-multidimensional-array)

Comment: That was. Thanks. I know it has to be something stupid but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

i'd use foreach:

```
foreach($json_post as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$j = '[{"a":"1", "b":"2"},{"a":"4", "b":"5"},{"a":"15", "b":"2"}]';

$decoded = json_decode($j, true);
//var_dump($decoded);


foreach ($decoded as $key => $post) {
   $valueOfA = $post['a'];
   $valueOfB = $post['b'];
}
```